# Make Progress Bar Smaller

Tags: html, css, progress-bar

Hey can somebody help me to make my progress bar smaller.

[image]

```
.progress-bar { 
    float: left; 
    width: 0%; 
    height: 100%; 
    font-size: 12px; 
    font-weight: 600; 
    line-height: 19px; 
    color: #ffffff; 
    text-align: center; 
    background-color: #999999; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); 
    box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); 
    -webkit-transition: width 0.6s ease; 
    -o-transition: width 0.6s ease; 
    transition: width 0.6s ease; 
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you currently have.

Comment: .progress-bar {
  float: left;
  width: 0%;
  height: 100%;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #999999;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -webkit-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  -o-transition: width 0.6s ease;
  transition: width 0.6s ease;
}

Comment: Can you add the relevant part of the HTML as well?

Answer (score 3):

To reduce the total width to 80% of screen width:

```
<progress value="40" max="100" style="width:80%">
```

Answer (score 0):

Your progress bar size is 100% of container in which it is.

Without HTML code, I can only guess to change your css from:

```
width: 0%;
```

To:

```
width: 60%;
```

Or even try with pixel values.